# save raw tuple into database - elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Need to save raw tuple into database.

values:

```
conn.adapter = {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Conn, {:http_req, #Port<0.14529>, ranch_tcp, :keepalive, #PID<0.528.0>, "GET",  :"HTTP/1.1", {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 2866}, "localhost", :undefined, 4000, "/click",  :undefined, "campaign_id=44", undefined, [],  [{"host", "localhost:4000"},   {"user-agent",    "Mozilla/5.0 X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"},   "accept",    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"},   {"accept-anguage", "en-US,en;q=0.5"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate"},   "cookie", _ga=GA1.1.1071807366.1485427699"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"},   {"upgrade-nsecure-requests", "1"}], [{"connection", ["keep-alive"]}],  :undefined, [], waiting, "", :undefined, false, :waiting, [], "",  :undefined}}
enter code here
```

tried as,

```
 field :field5, {:array, :string}

 P1.Repo.insert!(%P1.TestTable{field1: "Header Track",field2: ip, field3: conn.host, field5: conn.adapter})
```

but it throws error as,

```
TestTable.field5` in `insert` does not match type {:array, :string}
```

Or atleast, need those data to be converted to string and saved in db

Comment: could you give more information? like *what* is not working?

Comment: Can you tell why you want to do this? The tuple includes ports and pids as well which may not exist or be the same when you retrieve the value later. You can use `inspect` to convert it to a string if you just want to see the value later and don't need the exact value back. If you really want to store this exact value, there's `:erlang.term_to_binary/1` and `:erlang.binary_to_term/1` to serialize/deserialize arbitrary terms.

Comment: @zv sure, updated

Comment: @Dogbert , how can i convert to string and save in db

Comment: First off, the value you are saving doesn't make sense. As @Dogbert pointed out, you are attempting to store a reference to a particular process, which, without attempting to preserve the local state of execution is meaningless (and even then you are fighting the grain). You need to consider your data model & extract appropriate fields **OR** commit all *serializable* information to an unstructured data store.  Second, please give us your exact error message.

Comment: @zv_ Sure, updated

Comment: @petspandaD So... that means you've kind of got everything you need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tuple is not an array of strings. If you just want to be able to see the tuple's contents later and don't need the actual tuple with those values, you can use `inspect/1` to convert the tuple into a string representation and save it as a string:

```
# Schema
field :field5, :string

# Controller
Repo.insert(%TestTable{..., field5: inspect(conn.adapter)})
```

If you do need the tuple as a tuple later you can use [`:erlang.term_to_binary/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-1) to serialize and [`:erlang.binary_to_term/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_term-1) to deserialize. (Make sure to read the warning section in the documentation of `binary_to_term`.)

```
# Schema
field :field5, :binary

# Controller
Repo.insert(%TestTable{..., field5: :erlang.term_to_binary(conn.adapter)})

# Later
test = Repo.get(TestTable, 123)
adapter = :erlang.binary_to_term(test.field5, [:safe])
```